# JSON output in Ruby on Rails upon curl request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, curl, header

I have built a Ruby on rails app which uses HTML as default output.

Now I want to support JSON. 
When I use the command curl with flag `--header "Accept: application/json"` 
a JSON output should be returned.

Which implementation method do I need here?
The used method may not violate the REST rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read documentation on [how to render json](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data).

Basically, your need to tell your controller method it is to be able to respond to json :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid adding these lines of code to each def?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in writing respond formats in controller's actions. Though if you prefer something more dry, take a look at `responders` : http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html or https://github.com/plataformatec/responders

Comment: The HTML view is supported but when I send a request for the JSON representation index.json.erb is not returned.